# LIKE clause not working when used in a HAVING clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

This is my query in SQL Server. I want to group by each campaign that ends with this substring '[PROS]'.

However, the resultant table I included at the end has some others ending with '[RT]'

```
-- Metrics for Each Date & Specific Campaign
SELECT 
    campaign_name, 
    SUM(clicks) AS Total_Clicks
FROM 
    FB_Raw
GROUP BY 
    campaign_name
HAVING 
    campaign_name LIKE '%' + '[PROS]' + '%';

04_Remarketing_BOFU_3.31.2020 [RT]                      |  568
04_Remarketing_BOFU(optimize=PUR)_5.16.2020 [RT]        |  0
02_Prospecting_CBO_BidCaps_CH_6.29.20 [PROS]            |  2741
02_Prospecting_CostCaps$500_5.12.2020 [PROS]            |  7549
04_Remarketing_Content_ATC/IC_4.10.2020 [RT]            |  478
04_Remarketing_Content_Visitors_4.30.2020 [RT]          |  381
04_Remarketing_MOFU_3.31.2020 [RT]                      |  2005
04_Remarketing_BOFU_CH_6.29.20 [RT]                     |  9
02_Prospecting_LC_Broad_Narrative [PROS]                |  6261
02_Prospecting_CBO_BidCaps_OGCreative_6.9.2020 [PROS]   |  1405
02_Prospecting_LC_Broad_6.30.2020 [PROS]                |  2512
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must use the [`ESCAPE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#pattern-matching-with-the-escape-clause) character as the square brackets are used for [Pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#pattern-matching-by-using-like) when using [`LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). The escape character goes in front of any character you want to use the literal value of.

[`HAVING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) should be used for filtering on an aggregate result. [`WHERE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is for filtering the data before it is aggregated (when you are using aggregates). In your case you should use [`WHERE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of [`HAVING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
SELECT campaign_name, 
       SUM(clicks) AS Total_Clicks
FROM FB_Raw
WHERE campaign_name LIKE '%![PROS!]%' ESCAPE '!'
GROUP BY campaign_name;
```

Comment: Tysm sir, that was it. '[' were messing up my LIKE clause.

Comment: `HAVING` vs `WHERE` is not directly relevant to the question here (it's mainly a problem of escaping). Both versions would work with the correct escaping, but it's likely that `WHERE` will be more performant if predicate pushdown does not happen for the `HAVING` version.

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets have special meaning when used inside `like` clause. Without escaping, the pattern `%[PROS]%` matches any string containing `P`, `R`, `O` or `S`. Escape the square brackets like so:

```
LIKE '%[[]PROS]%'
```

Comment: Tysm sir, your solution also works. '[' were messing up my LIKE clause.